# About storing the number of rows that can be found through an queries in a different table

Tags: database

I made a review services now. and i have a questions.

Is 'storing the number of rows that can be found through an queries in a different table' a way used in bussiness and not wrong?

For example, In my review service, each review has a score ranging from 1 to 5. And we need an API that calculates the average of reviews and an API that calculates the number of scores for each review.

But in my opinion, it is better to store the average of review scores and the number of review scores separately in a separate table and update them to manage them rather than performing lookup operations through db indexing operations.

I haven't had this experience, so I'm wondering if my idea is the right way and if it's okay to use it in business.

*My english skill is not good so if you have any questions, please comment me. :)*

I've tried googling to find data on these things, but I haven't found anything related and I don't know the keywords.

Please let me know if there are any keywords related to this.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` (`SUM AVG`)will probably do somewhat identical to what you are suggesting. More ticklish are efficient queries and having (not too many) Indices. So forget it.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for above scenario changes based on the amount of data and user behavior. We can do a simple calculation with above use case.
System design questions are solved using assumptions.

Let's assume that if 1000 users view the page, 500 of them add/update the review rating. Calculating the average, count of reviews is a difficult task and should be minimized.

case 1: Calculate average every time - we calculate aggregate data 1000 times.

case 2: save data in different table - we calculate aggregate data 500 times.

It is better to save the aggregate data in other table and fetch it instead of calculating it every time.